# Amazon EC2 Windows Instance still showing nginx home page with public ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, amazon-ec2, nssm

I have created a windows amazon ec2 instance and setup a flask app on it. **localhost** opens the required home page. Then is used **waitress-serve** to host the **app.py** file and also created a service with **nssm**. After that i download and execute the **nginx.exe**. Now my ec2 public ip shows the nginx home page. After modifying the **nginx.conf** file i expected to see the home page and not nginx home page but i still get the nginx home page. Following is my nginx.conf file text

```
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    #include       mime.types;
    #default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    #sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    
    upstream flaskhelloworld {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name my_public_ip;
        listen  [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://flaskhelloworld;
        }
    }


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check deleting the cache of your browser or opening in a private tab.

Comment: no it does not work. same issue